# Getting unknown type for RetryPolicy error after upgrading spring data cassandra to latest 2.0.7.RELEASE

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I updated these lines of code to support for spring-data-cassandra-2.0.7.RELEASE:

```
CassandraOperations cOps = new CassandraTemplate(session);
```

From:

```
Insert insertStatement = (Insert)statement;
CqlTemplate.addWriteOptions(insertStatement, queryWriteOptions);
cOps.execute(insertStatement);
```

To:

```
Insert insertStatement = (Insert)statement;
insertStatement = QueryOptionsUtil.addWriteOptions(insertStatement, 
queryWriteOptions);
cOps.insert(insertStatement);
```

Above changes are throwing below error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown type [interface com.datastax.driver.core.policies.RetryPolicy] for property [retryPolicy] in entity [com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Insert]; only primitive types and Collections or Maps of primitive types are allowed
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.getDataType(BasicCassandraPersistentProperty.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.lambda$null$10(CassandraMappingContext.java:552)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.lambda$getDataTypeWithUserTypeFactory$11(CassandraMappingContext.java:542)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.getDataTypeWithUserTypeFactory(CassandraMappingContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.CassandraMappingContext.getDataType(CassandraMappingContext.java:486)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getPropertyTargetType(MappingCassandraConverter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.lambda$getTargetType$0(MappingCassandraConverter.java:682)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getTargetType(MappingCassandraConverter.java:670)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.getWriteValue(MappingCassandraConverter.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInsertFromWrapper(MappingCassandraConverter.java:403)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInsertFromObject(MappingCassandraConverter.java:360)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:345)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:320)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.QueryUtils.createInsertQuery(QueryUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:442)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:430)
```

Query that is passed as input is of type com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Insert containing:

```
INSERT INTO person (name,id,age) VALUES ('name01','123',23) USING TIMESTAMP 1528922717378000 AND TTL 60;
```

And the queryoptions containing RetryPolicy and consistency level is passed.
Based on documentation followed above changes are not working. Can anyone let me know what is wrong here?

I'm using Spring 2.0.7.RELEASE with Cassandra driver 3.5.0

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work with it using below changes:

```
cOps.getCqlOperations().execute(insertStatement);
```

How can i check the consistency level if it got applied?

Comment: After running the query; I explicitly checked for existing consistency level from the CQL terminal and guaranteed the last CL applied everytime.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this works:

```
batchOps.insert(ImmutableSet.of(entity), insertOptions);
```